# nested for loop doesn't give all outputs

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

I'm supposed to get 16 outputs where each of the values from each of the for loops are multiplied each other but for some reason I'm getting only 4 out puts where only the 4000 value of `K` is being multiplied with all values of `D`. Can some one tell me where I went wrong?

```
def main():
    for i in range(0,4):
        for j in range(0,4):
            if j==0:
                K=1000
            elif j==1:
                K=2000
            elif j==2:
                K=2500
            else:
                K=4000

        if i==0:
            D=2
        elif i==1:
            D=4
        elif i==2:
            D=5.5
        else:
            D=10

        print("The year with depth",D,"and K as",K,"is",K*D)

main()
```

Comment: instead of tons of `if`s use list of dictionary and `i`, `j` as index to it.

Comment: Your identation if wrong. And your print should be inside de inner loop, otherwise all your `K`s will be printed as `4000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is important and your print statement must be in the inner for loop.

```
def main():
        for i in range(0,4):

                if i==0:
                        D=2
                elif i==1:
                        D=4
                elif i==2:
                        D=5.5
                else:
                        D=10

                for j in range(0,4):
                        if j==0:
                                K=1000
                        elif j==1:
                                K=2000
                        elif j==2:
                                K=2500
                        else:
                                K=4000
                        print("The year with depth",D,"and K as",K,"is",K*D)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-arrange your code, first declarations last `print`:

```
def main():
    for i in range(0,4):
        if i==0:
            D=2
        elif i==1:
            D=4
        elif i==2:
            D=5.5
        else:
            D=10
        for j in range(0,4):
            if j==0:
                K=1000
            elif j==1:
                K=2000
            elif j==2:
                K=2500
            else:
                K=4000
            print("The year with depth",D,"and K as",K,"is",K*D)
```

Also, one pythonic way of doing that would be:

```
for D in (2, 4, 5.5, 10):
    for K in range(1000, 5000, 1000):
        print("The year with depth",D,"and K as",K,"is",K*D)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting 4 outputs only, becasue your `print()` is **outside** second loop. Welcome to python indentation nightmare :)